# Assigning numeric value on the basis of positive or negative entry and sum up

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with approx 200 columns like below

```
1376        PSEN1   1.4057115  0.1254332   0.1254332
1377        PSMA2  -1.6285915  1.2343333   1.2343333
1378        PSMA3   0.7547530 -3.0000000   0.8299074
1379        PSMA4  -0.9455922  0.0000000  -1.6285915
1380        PSMA6   0.8299074 32.0065000   1.5311143
1381        PSMB2  -2.0481873  0.0000000  -2.4958000
1382        PSMB3   1.5311188  2.4958000   0.0000456
1383        PSMB5   1.5259254  5.0000456   3.6538010
1384        PSMB7   0.6538010  5.0654087   2.4934745
```

I need to assign values 2 for positive entry and -2 for negative and then do row sum. Is there any efficient way to do this otherwise i need to run the loop and check condition and then assign values by writing a long code.

Desired output something like

```
1376        PSEN1   2   2   2   6
1377        PSMA2  -2   2   2   2
1378        PSMA3   2  -2   2   2
```

Here only three rows are displayed. Thanks

Comment: what about entries that are 0? are they "converted" to 0 (as in @akrun's solution), to -2 or to 2 (both last options, as in my solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that we wanted to change the values in all the columns except the first two, get the `sign` of the columns (`df1[-(1:2)]`) and multiply by 2.  If we need to create a new column ('newCol'), then use `rowSums` on the changed column values.

```
 df1[-(1:2)] <- sign(df1[-(1:2)])*2
 df1$newCol <- rowSums(df1[-(1:2)])
 head(df1,3)
 #    V1    V2 V3 V4 V5 newCol
 #1 1376 PSEN1  2  2  2      6
 #2 1377 PSMA2 -2  2  2      2
 #3 1378 PSMA3  2 -2  2      2
```

NOTE: I replaced the values with the new values based on the expected output.  You can make a copy of the original dataset if required.

Or use `Reduce`

```
 df1$newCol <- Reduce(`+`, df1[-(1:2)])
```

#### Update

If `0` belongs to positive category,

```
rowSums(`dim<-`(c(-2, 2)[(df1[-(1:2)]>=0)+1L], dim(df1[-(1:2)])))
#[1]  6  2  2 -2  6 -2  6  6  6
```

Or based on the original solution,

```
rowSums((sign(df1[-(1:2)]) + !df1[-(1:2)])*2)
#[1]  6  2  2 -2  6 -2  6  6  6
```

#### data

```
df1 <-   structure(list(V1 = 1376:1384, V2 = c("PSEN1", "PSMA2", 
"PSMA3", 
"PSMA4", "PSMA6", "PSMB2", "PSMB3", "PSMB5", "PSMB7"), 
V3 = c(1.4057115, 
-1.6285915, 0.754753, -0.9455922, 0.8299074, -2.0481873, 1.5311188, 
1.5259254, 0.653801), V4 = c(0.1254332, 1.2343333, -3, 0, 32.0065, 
0, 2.4958, 5.0000456, 5.0654087), V5 = c(0.1254332, 1.2343333, 
0.8299074, -1.6285915, 1.5311143, -2.4958, 4.56e-05, 3.653801, 
2.4934745)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"),
class =    "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: @akrun, in your solution, entries that are 0 are converted to 0

Comment: @CathG I updated the post.  It was not sure from the post where 0 belongs to.  I did notice it but the expected output showed were only 3 lines.  Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Another way in one line and without changing the values in df, assuming 0 is assigned for entries that are 0:

```
rowSums(ifelse(df1[, 3:5]==0, 0, ifelse(df1[, 3:5]>0, 2, -2)))
# [1]  6  2  2 -2  6 -2  6  6  6
```

***NB: if you need to change the value in df1, you can do:***

```
df1[, 3:5] <- ifelse(df1[, 3:5]==0, 0, ifelse(df1[, 3:5]>0, 2, -2)); rowSums(df1[, 3:5])
```